# How can a VPN connection be maintained after closing its port?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, ports

Consider a VPN server with its ports closed using port knocking to open ports only upon a successful knock sequence.

When a closed port is opened up using port knocking, and then a VPN connection is established, why is it possible for the VPN connection to stay connected after automatically closing the port after a configured amount of time?

This is something I saw in a howtogeek.com article on port knocking without further explanation so maybe I'm just not understanding it correctly.

My understanding was that closed ports mean they're not listening to connections nor will they maintain established connections. So what is happening when you temporarily open a port to *establish* the connection and then automatically close it *while keeping the already established VPN session connected*?

Does the connection actually persist over the closed port or is there something else happening with regards to the VPN protocol where the established connection happens elsewhere? And would this type of situation with connections maintaining after a port closes be possible with something like SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now usually statefull firewall used. It allow filter new (first) connection and established (belong to known connections) packet separately.

At first it make simple to allow any outbound connection (with bidirectional data-packet transfer), while inbound connections still disabled.

So if port open for new connection long enough to establish connection. Next this connection keep work ower rules for packets with status="established".

Example of simple modern stateful firewall: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/simple_stateful_firewall#Example_iptables.rules_file

```
/etc/iptables/iptables.rules

# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Sun Mar 17 14:21:12 2013
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 17 14:21:12 2013
```